# stripe firebase callable function returning null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I made a firebase callable function to call stripe api to get a stripe customer object

```
exports.getDefaultPayment = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  await stripe.customers.retrieve("cus_H5UarU16gpUbqM", (customer) => {
    // asynchronously called
    return customer;
  });
});
```

then I’m trying to simply log that object

```
onPress={() => {
              const getDefaultPayment = functions().httpsCallable(
                'getDefaultPayment'
              );
              getDefaultPayment().then((result) => {
                console.log(JSON.parse(result.data));
              });
            }}
```

but the result is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callable function isn't actually returning anything to the client.  You need a return statement at the top level, not inside a callback.  Also, it seems you're mixing up callbacks with async/await, which doesn't make sense.  Just use await - don't bother with the callback.  Perhaps this will work:

```
return stripe.customers.retrieve("cus_H5UarU16gpUbqM")
```